# Description of an Increasing Maximum Value in a Sequence of Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this sequence when visiting the [*Longest increasing subsequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem. In particular, [this implementation](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/dynamic_programming/lis).  I will demonstrate the observation below:

**Given**

Here we have a sequence of integers:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 6]
```

Notice from left to right, at each position, the next number is either:

1. a value already observed
2. a number larger than the maximum value observed

Thus the following pattern is invalid:

```
[0, 5, 1, ...]
```

as the value after 5 must be observed prior or larger than 5.

**Question**

What is the mathematical term of such a sequence?  If no exact term is defined, how might this be formally described?  The sequence is not strictly monotonic, but the maximum appears to be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any name for it, but you could formally define such a sequence as: $(a_n)$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_i \geq a_j$ whenever $i > j$. Of course you could specify bounds on the indices if the sequence it finite. Also it follows from this that the first element is the smallest element.